# Не работает команда pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Решил установить новую библиотеку на питоне (send2trash) через pip и вышла ошибка

```
C:\python>pip install send2trash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "c:\users\aleksandr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3251, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "c:\users\aleksandr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aleksandr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3263, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "c:\users\aleksandr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "c:\users\aleksandr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "c:\users\aleksandr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.2.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39845636

Comment: Вася, но у меня Windows10

Comment: и что, что win10? там вполне нормальные ответы, заменить просто пути в ответах на ваши